# Does jQuery work pretty well on Mac?

Tags: jquery, macos, cross-browser, compatibility

I have a client that I am doing a very small project for. His company uses Macs exclusively. I rarely use Mac and don't have one for testing.

If I use jQuery and test it with FireFox on Windows, can I assume it will also work for FireFox for Mac? How about other Mac browsers?

I am considering just not using much JS/Ajax, but don't want to shoot myself in the foot. Has anyone got a lot of jQuery / Mac compatibility experience?

**Edit: A quick note:**

Yes, I am aware that JavaScript (and thus jQuery) is a browser-based language.

However, while I haven't done much JavaScript lately (hence the question) I do remember having any number of problems back in the day with browser versions on the same OS, and even more problems across multiple OS.

Don't want to date myself too much, but think back in the day, debugging complex JavaScript in multiple versions of IE and (shudder) Netscape across multiple OS.

Anyway, after some testing, it appears to work just fine =o)

Comment: You should know that Mac comes bundled with Safari which should be the most commonly used browser. And I'm on a Mac with Chrome. So, testing in firefox should not be enough (depending on what you're doing, but why take the chance?)

Comment: i think jquery(javascript) runs on browser .. correct me if i am wrong!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A browser's JavaScript engine is expected to behave the same on whatever platform the browser is run on, because the JS engine doesn't really interact much with the OS; it just lives in the browser process. So no, you shouldn't encounter Mac-specific problems with your scripts.

[Safari 5.1.7 is still available for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1539) if you need to test in that. For any new visitors to this post: Safari 6 is not available for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is a client side javascript based. It entirely depends on the browser itself which you are using in mac.

Jquery itself doesn't interact with Mac , Linux or windows.

Answer (score 1):

It works awesome on Mac, pc and Linux. I would recommend though you download safari for windows to test in.

Answer (score 0):

jquery tries to work on all browsers and on all platforms. if you look at nettuts the guy who runs the blog uses a mac all the time to test out his jquery stuff.

also, jquery [moved away from testing browser versions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) in favor of testing for features, so the browser difference should be handled gracefully if something isnt available.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some really weird things on Mac when using jQuery (or any JavaScript library).

The biggest odd thing is sometimes Mac's don't like relative paths.
so instead of using

```
<script src="js/someFile.js"></script>
```

I now use

```
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/js/someFile.js"></script>
```

I can't explain it but after enough people with Macs call and say something doesn't work, this usually fixes it for me.